# Для каждой вкладки своя глобальная переменная?

Tags: python, django

Мне нужна глобальная переменная otv(или любое другое хранилище на замену), которая будет сохранять сообщения, а потом на страницу эти сообщения будут выводиться при отправке формы. Проблема в том, что при открытии 2-ой вкладки в браузере эта переменная  сохраняет свое значение, и при выводе прошлые сообщения с 1-ой вкладки отображаются (хотя я их не вводил на 2-ой вкладке). Что делать?

Файл urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from hello import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.main),
]
```

Файл views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

otv=""

def main(request):
    global otv
    mes=request.POST.get("text2", "")
    otv=otv+"\n"+mes
    data={"tex":otv}
    return render(request, "index.html", context=data)
```

html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>MyTeacher</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="text" readonly class="space">{{tex}}</textarea>
<p></p>
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<textarea name="text2" class="space2"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="SEND" class="but"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А в чём смысл? Если вы хотите, чтобы сообщения сохранялить только в пределах вкладки - зачем их вообще отправлять из вкладки на сервер?

Comment: Я вопрос ответ делаю, в данном случает пример для простоты. Ввожу в поле ввода, передается в main, там отвечает chat gpt. В пределах одной вкладки должен вестись один диалог и должна быть одна глобальная переменная с записями вопросов и ответов. Перехожу на новую  и переменная в идеале должна быть другая. Планировал выгружать это куда-нибудь в файл, но как потом понять с какой вкладки я отправил запрос(1-ая, 2-ая, 3-я), чтобы понять в какой файл писать? @andreymal

Comment: Ну тогда придумывайте для вкладок какие-нибудь идентификаторы, чтобы по этим идентификаторам различать разные вкладки

Comment: А ещё имейте в виду, что WSGI-процессы будут иметь отдельные друг от друга глобальные переменные и что они могут перезапускаться в любой момент с потерей всех глобальных переменных, так что глобальные переменные это плохое хранилище

Comment: А как это сделано на других сайтах? На всех чатгпт подобных.  Там при открытии 1-ой вкладки отправляется запрос , создается тут же диалог(выгружается куда-то, может в файл). Дописывается в файл и на странице.   Открываешь 2-ую вкладку - диалог сохранен, кнопка его где-то слева.  Пустая страница , вводишь  запросы , получаешь ответы, все заново, ответов/запросов с первой вкладки нет (как будто глобальные переменные другие и имеют исходные значения).

Comment: Так вы уж определитесь, вы хотите сохранять или не хотите сохранять? Если вы хотите хранить все диалоги пользователя и позволить ему переключаться между разными диалогами — ну тогда заведите ещё идентификатор для пользователя и свяжите его с идентификаторами диалогов, которые этот пользователь создавал

Comment: Собственно, в Django для идентификации пользователей уже есть [сессии](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/) (но сессии через время удаляются, и если надо сохранять всё навсегда, то придётся городить полноценную регистрацию с логином и паролем)

Comment: Мне пока без сохранения диалогов. Мне хотя бы чтоб было 1 вкладка =1 диалог без подрубления запросов/ответов с прошлых вкладок.

Comment: Ну тогда придумайте идентификаторы для вкладок/диалогов да и всё

Answer (score -1):

Возможно твоя проблема связана с тем, что каждая вкладка браузера работает с одним и тем же глобальным контекстом, поэтому переменная `otv` сохраняется между вкладками.

Лично моя рекомендация это использовать хранилище переменных, такое как сессия Django или база данных.

Вот так выглядит пример для сохранения сообщений между вкладками.

Файл primer.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

def main(request):
    mes = request.POST.get("text2", "")
    
    if "otv" not in request.session:
        request.session"otv" = ""
    
    request.session"otv" += "\n" + mes  # Добавляем новое сообщение к существующему содержимому "otv"
    
    data = {"tex": request.session"otv"}
    
    return render(request, "index.html", context=data)
```

Теперь каждая вкладка будет иметь свою отдельную сессию, где переменная `otv` будет храниться отдельно для каждой вкладки.

> P.S для использования сессий в Django, убедись, что у тебя настроена поддержка сессий в файле settings.py. Ты должен установить и настроить соответствующий хранилище сессий, такое как база данных или файловая система.